# Emacsclient not focusing if called with --eval argument from terminal

Tags: emacsclient, command-line-arguments

I wish to call man function in emacsclient when I typing "man smth" in terminal. When I open files from iterm via emacsclient - emacs gaining focus and when I kill buffer - terminal gaining focus back. But when I want not open file but evaluate "man ls" for example - its evaluating in emacs, but not switching to emacs and when I close man buffer its not switching back.

Here's my command to open man page from iterm in emacs:

```
emacsclient -c -e "(man \"ls\")" -a ""
```

Can anyone point me what am I doing wrong plz? Thx.

Comment: or use `--tty` to display it in the terminal ;)

Answer (score 2):

New windows not getting focus seems to be an [issue with the OS/window manager](https://major.io/2015/07/06/allow-new-windows-to-steal-focus-in-gnome-3/), not Emacs.

There are a lot of search results suggesting various hacks at either the [Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636694/emacsclient-window-focus) or [OS](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/485s8o/emacsclient_new_terminal_frame_does_not_get_focus/) level, but my preferred solution is to use the [scripts suggested by MJ Wall](http://mjwall.com/blog/2013/10/04/how-i-use-emacs/). These have explicit `raise-frame` actions.